# How to convert a string into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an problem that usr_inp is a string.

```
 class Student:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        return "Hello " + str(self.name)


justin = Student("Justin")
eva = Student("Eva")

usr_inp = input("Enter your name : ")

if usr_inp == "justin" or "eva":
    print(usr_inp.greet())
```

So I know how to fix the problem here, there are other several ways but I want a way to change the usr_inp the variable used above.
Help me

Comment: `if usr_inp == "justin" or "eva"` is wrong.

Comment: `if usr_inp in ("justin", "eva"):print(Student(usr_inp).greet())`

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is wrong and `usr_inp` is a `string` which doesn't implement `greet()` method while `justin` and `eva` are instance of `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
justin = Student("Justin")
eva = Student("Eva")

usr_inp = input("Enter your name : ")

if usr_inp == "justin" or "eva":
    print(usr_inp.greet())
```

to this:

```
usr_inp = input("Enter your name : ")

if usr_inp == "Justin" or usr_inp == "Eva":
    print(Student(usr_inp).greet())
```

Comment: `usr_inp` is a `str` which does not implement `greet` method.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines are wrong,

```
if usr_inp == "justin" or "Eva":
    print(usr_inp.greet())
```

It should be like this,

```
usr_inp = input("Enter your name : ")

if usr_inp == "justin" or usr_inp == "eva":
    print(Student(usr_inp).greet())
```